# Unable to understand Malloc output

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *p;
    p=malloc(1);
    scanf("%s",p);
    printf("%s",p);
    free(p);
}
```

the code takes only 27 characters after which segmentation fault occurs.Can anybody explain this strange behavior of malloc(1)?

Comment: I don't find it strange at all. What were you expecting to happen? What do you think `malloc(1)` does?

Comment: @1336087: Even one character would be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There has to be room for `scanf` to add the null terminator.

Comment: @FredLarson: Yes, OP should allocate at least 2 bytes. And use `scanf("%1s",p);` or `fgets()`.

Answer (score 4):

You're only allocating a single byte.  A segfault is fair game at any point after the first byte in your example.  It just happens to be 27 bytes for you.  It could be different every time you run your program

EDIT:
If you mean to only allocate one bye to read a single character, change your functions to:

```
scanf(" %c", p);
printf("%c", p);
```

The leading space in front of the character specifier on the scanf is to trick scanf into ignoring any white space that it may try to assign to your buffer (if any exists)